# Prohibit automatic linebreaks in Pycharm Output when using large Matrices

Tags: python, matrix, output, pycharm, line-breaks

I'm working in PyCharm on Windows. In the project I'm currently working on I have "large" matrices, but when i output them Pycharm automatically adds linebreaks so that one row occupys two lines instead of just one:

```
 [[ 3.         -1.73205081  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
       0.          0.          0.        ]
     [-1.73205081  1.         -1.         -2.          0.          0.          0.
       0.          0.          0.        ]
     [ 0.         -1.          1.          0.         -1.41421356  0.          0.
       0.          0.          0.        ]
     [ 0.         -2.          0.          1.         -1.41421356  0.
      -1.73205081  0.          0.          0.        ]
     [ 0.          0.         -1.41421356 -1.41421356  0.         -1.41421356
       0.         -1.41421356  0.          0.        ]
     [ 0.          0.          0.          0.         -1.41421356  0.          0.
       0.         -1.          0.        ]
     [ 0.          0.          0.         -1.73205081  0.          0.          3.
      -1.73205081  0.          0.        ]
     [ 0.          0.          0.          0.         -1.41421356  0.
      -1.73205081  1.         -2.          0.        ]
     [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.         -1.          0.
      -2.          0.         -1.73205081]
     [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
       0.         -1.73205081  0.        ]]
```

It make my results very hard to reed and to compare. The window is big enough so that everything should be displayed but it still breaks the rows. Is there any setting to prevent this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PyCharm default console width is set to 80 characters.
Lines are printed without wrapping unless you set `soft wrap` in options:
`File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Console -> Use soft wraps in console`.

However both options make reading big matrices hard.
You can fix this in few ways.

With this test code:

```
import random
m = [[random.random() for a in range(10)] for b in range(10)]
print(m)
```

You can try one of these:

## Pretty print

Use `pprint` module, and override line *width*:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(m, width=300)
```

## Numpy

For *numpy* version *1.13* and lower:

If you use `numpy` module, configure *arrayprint* option:

```
import numpy
numpy.core.arrayprint._line_width = 300
print(numpy.matrix(m))
```

For *numpy* version *1.14* and above *(thanks to @Alex Johnson)*:

```
import numpy
numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=300)
print(numpy.matrix(m))
```

## Pandas

If you use `pandas` module, configure *display.width* option:

```
import pandas
pandas.set_option('display.width', 300)
print(pandas.DataFrame(m))
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but modifying numpy's line_width property in the manner listed above didn't work for me. This, however, did work: `numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=300)`