# Print output of dataframe with 11 columns in same view - Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I am using pycharm and I have a DF output which has 11 columns and it is being printed with wrapped , i need to scroll to see the complete output, any setting to change this in pycharm

Comment: Have you tried any of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952715/prohibit-automatic-linebreaks-in-pycharm-output-when-using-large-matrices/43954098#43954098

Comment: awesome, the one with Pandas option worked.. Thanks. How can i accept this as answer?

Comment: just up-vote my answer on the other question if you found it useful. This question probably will be deleted as duplicate.