# Getting rid of ellipses in VS Code

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to write my python code and I am trying to view this array in the terminal. The array is fairly large so the terminal uses ellipses. Is there any way in the code itself to view the entire array without writing it to a text file per se?

Here is the array example

```
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.] 
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prohibit automatic linebreaks in Pycharm Output when using large Matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952715/prohibit-automatic-linebreaks-in-pycharm-output-when-using-large-matrices) this is my answer for PyCharm but I think it should work for VScode also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [set_printoptions()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=5)
print(np.arange(100))
np.set_printoptions(threshold=1000)
print(np.arange(100))
```

Output

```
[ 0  1  2 ... 97 98 99]
```

versus

```
 [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
  24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
  48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71
  72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95
  96 97 98 99]
```